# Using linked server from Windows 10 PC

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, authentication, connectivity, windows-10

I have been using SQL Server linked servers for years, and they have been working fine. But now when I try to run a query (on a machine with Windows 10) using linked server I get this error:

> Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'

If I then run the same query on my older machine without Windows 10, I have no problems and never ever had any problems.

Now the funny part begins: If I run the query from my old PC (logged on with the same credentials) and then within 5 minutes run the same query from my Windows 10 machine - there is no problem!

It's like if my old machine establishes a connection that is open for about 5 minutes and then times out, and my Windows 10 machine cannot find out how to establish that connection.

Any ideas?

I am just running a query in SSMS logged onto server A querying data from a database on server B, and doing the same thing on both machines.

Comment: Are these local SQL instances on both machines?  If so, I'd look at the 'Security' tab in the linked server properties.  Are they the same?

Comment: Yeah, what are your security settings? Are you using the same methods of  logging in/authorizing on both linked servers?

Comment: Did you ever get a resolution here?  I have the same issue: Connect using SSMS windows authentication to remote MSSQL server A, which has a linked MSSQL server B defined.  Queries that only use server A are fine.  Queries that involve server B return the "Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'" error, but only if the workstation SSMS is connecting from is on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

The error "Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'" means that SQL Server is not running under a service account on the new PC.  Open the control panel, go to administrative and last open services.  Look for SQL Server and see what it is logging in as.  Create a Active directory account (sort of like an account for a person, except nobody should use it) and put the "domain\serviceaccount" and password into the login as tab.  Be sure to grant "domain\serviceaccount" access to the remote server.

Comment: Hi 
thanx for answering.
There are no service called 'SQL Server' - on neither the old or the new PC.
Why is that service needed? I am supposed to use my own AD-credentials at - not a service account. 
It has never been an issue with my colleagues or with my own older PC (all using Win7)

Comment: If there is no service called SQL Service then, it would be a named instance. please post the result of below query from SQL: select serverproperty('servername')